# Power BI Drilldown Choropleth Custom Map Display Issues

Tags: powerbi, topojson, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to create a map visual that shows sales by geography within the US by using the Power BI Drilldown Choropleth visual.  I can get the visual to work correctly when using the shapefiles from the US Census Bureau's website (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html) and converting them to the Topojson format using mapshaper.org.

However when using my custom shapefiles which have custom regions and subregions the map only has one region bolded with the other ones grayed out, and when hovering over each region it only shows the sales of one of the regions no matter which region I am selecting.  The numbers should change and show each region's sales when hovering the mouse over that region.

After several hours of searching online for a solution and coming up empty, I thought I would modify my shapefile to only one region to see if I can get one region to work.  To my surprise, the region was mapped correctly, but the problem that occurred was that the region was not highlighted, but the rest of the map was.  In other words, when hovering over the region with the mouse nothing would show up, but when I hovered over any other part of the map the region's sales would appear.

Has anyone had any similar experience?  Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.